# Import objects from a python module that has the same name as an __init__ import

Tags: python, module

The project is structured as follows:

```
dir/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
```

Foo.py has a function that uses a local assignment:

```
"""foo.py"""

BAR = 12345
def foo():
    # do something with BAR
```

My goal is to import the object `BAR` to use in my own code. However, `__init__.py` contains an import of bar that masks any attempt to import from `foo` as a module:

```
"""__init__.py"""

from dir.foo import foo
```

So when I interact with the package, I'm only able to see `dir.foo` as a function definition instead of a module. How can I get access to `dir.foo.BAR`?

Answer (score 1):

Lame hack:

```
import sys
foo_module = sys.modules["dir.foo"]
bar = foo_module.BAR
```

Better way might be to ask the author of `dir` not to shadow the submodule name within the top-level namespace, for example by avoiding naming a function the same way as the module in which it was defined.